# Decidability of determining whether a context-free grammar generates all strings in 1*

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, context-free, decision-problem

How could I prove that the following language is decidable?

$\{\langle G\rangle \mid G\ \text{is a CFG over}\ \{0,1\}\ \text{and}\ 1^* \subseteq L(G)\}$

P.S. 
It's the problem 4.15 of the third edition of the "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" by Michael Sipser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the solutions to the exercises of that book [here](https://github.com/ryandougherty/Introduction-to-the-Theory-of-Computation-Solutions/blob/master/chapter4.tex). For completeness of the answer, I rewrite the solution (with some more details) here.

Let $p$ be an upper bound of the [pumping length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages#Formal_statement) of $G$, you only need to check whether $1^0, 1^1,\ldots,1^{p+p!} \in G$. If not, we can certainly reject $\langle G\rangle$. Otherwise, applying pumping lemma on $1^k$ ($p\le k\le p + p!$), we can conclude that there exist substrings $u,v,w,x,y$ such that

- $1^k=uvwxy$, which means $u,v,w,x,y$ contain only 1s,
- $|vwx|\le \text{pumping length} \le p$,
- $|vx|\ge1$ and
- $uv^nwx^ny\in G$, i.e. $1^{|uwy|+n|vx|}=1^{k+(n-1)|vx|}\in G$, for all $n\ge 0$, which means $1^{k+n(p!)}\in G$ for all $n\ge0$.

Note $\{1^{k+n(p!)}\mid n\ge0, p\le k\le p + p!\}$ covers all $1^m$ for large $m$, so $1^0, 1^1,\ldots,1^{p+p!} \in G$ indeed implies $1^*\subseteq G$.

Comment: Thanks, but the only thing I cannot realize that is the p+p!. 
Could you explain more about that?

Comment: @javadr $p!$ is a multiple of all possible $|vx|$, so to make $1^{k+(n-1)|vx|}$ cover all $1^m$ for large $m$, it is natural to let $k$ range from $p$ to $p+p!$.